How to install Paragon APFS_lke_9.7.11_b776 on Ubuntu24?
I purchased APFS for Linux from Paragon and having issues installing it.
Background:
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on iMac desktop (late 2013 model) partitioned to dual-boot MacOS and Ubuntu. The MacOS partition is in APFS format. I have an Apple Airport external HDD for Time Machine operated by MacOS that is also in APFS format. I also have an external 4TB HDD (Seagate IronWolf) connected by USB where I store my big files, that's also in APFS format. I would like to access (read/write) these two APFS external HDDs and perhaps also the MacOS partition on the internal HDD (an SSD 2TB drive) but that's secondary.
My Linux kernel version is 6.8.0-40-generic (did uname -r in terminal).
Attempts:
When I follow the instructions on the screenshot over the Paragon website, I get this error in the terminal - see the screenshot.
enter image description here
I got the same error after removing and re-installing Ubuntu
I contacted Paragon and opened a case but they took 5 days and still have not replied.
Their official user's manual dates to 2022 and references kernel version as potentially the source of problems.
What should I do? I am at loss. Literally since I paid for the software. I need read/write so I can't consider FUSE and what not (and never understood how that works).

FUSE is read write. As for the software you have purchased did you verify before you paid for it that it works with the not sure version of Ubuntu you are using?

I couldn't find how to install FUSE: Everything I came across didn't work.
Yes I verified: They say they update their software within one month after a kernel update, among other fine print that clearly indicated it should work either immediately or within a month. That they didn't revert to support request in five days drove me here. Thanks for suggesting construction solutions that work.

You have answered your own question.

Their official user's manual dates to 2022 and references kernel version as potentially the source of problems.

Yes it is. It seems the author of the software haven't updated it for version 24.04 of Ubuntu, and so the kernel module is not compatible.
Before buying anything, you should ensure that it actually runs on the intended system, which unfortunately isn't the case here.
There is a free alternative available here called linux-apfs-rw, which was updated 2 weeks ago, so it seems the project is still alive.

Thank you for pointing to that link. I am very new to Linux and don't know how to install that, where to start... Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

You would need to use the command line to build and install the linux-apfs-rw kernel module. First read the tutorials, and then ultimately ask a new question if you need further help. Thanks.
